# How to tackle the Annual cycle?

Tags: sharepoint, office365

We are experimenting with Annual cycle in our company for some workloads we have to repeat every week, month, year etc...

So far we have tried:

- Teams calender
- Microsoft Planner
- Classic SharePoint Online Task list with Gantt (modern doesnt support Gantt)
- Custom list in SharePoint Online (with some SPD and or Flow attached for the logic)

Anybody have any better suggestions we can try out inside the Microsoft umbrella? Only 2 stipulations

1. It has to be OOTB functionality so no extra coding of any kind
2. No 3rd party software